# How to catch SQL::Parser errors in Perl

Tags: perl

I have an update statement which I am parsing with SQL::Parser

```
uPdate scott.emp 
set ename='SCT%',emp_date=TO_DATE('04/16/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),empno='15645' 
WHERE dept=20 and ename IN(select ename from emp where empno='1111');
```

But since TO_DATE function cannot be parsed with SQL::Parser hence it throws error:

```
Incomplete SET clause! at ./post_audit.pl line 173
Incomplete SET clause! at ./post_audit.pl line 173
```

How do I catch such errors? Does eval do the trick? Did not find proper documentation for the same.

Code to parse the SQL statements:

```
   +12  use SQL::Parser;

   +34  my $statement = "uPdate scott.emp set ename='SCT%',emp_date=TO_DATE('04/16/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),empno='15645' WHERE dept=20 and ename IN(select ename from emp where empno='1111')";

  +172      my $parser = SQL::Parser->new('AnyData', {RaiseError=>1} );
  +173      $parser->parse($statement);
```

Error is thrown at line 173 while parsing the statement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that "TO_DATE" function is the source of your error.

The [source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JZUCKER/SQL-Statement-1.004/lib/SQL/Parser.pm) to SQL::Parser module says:

```
my @sets = split /,/,$set_string;
my(@cols,@vals);
for(@sets) {
    my($col,$val) = split / = /,$_;
    return $self->do_err('Incomplete SET clause!') if !$col or !$val;
```

Note the "`=`" is surrounded by spaces in the regex: "`/ = /`"

Therefore, you should space-surround your equals signs:

```
set ename='SCT%'
```

should be

```
set ename = 'SCT%'
```

etc...

---

As far as handling it, it depends on which error flags you set in the constructor:

```
    sub do_err {
        ...
        warn $err if $self->{"PrintError"};
        die if $self->{"RaiseError"};
        return undef;
    }
```

- If you set `RaiseError` flag, the code will die.

  ```
  my $parser = SQL::Parser->new('AnyData', {RaiseError=>1} );
  ```

  As such, you need to wrap an `eval {}` around the `$parser->parse()` call, and check `$@` value for error string.
- If you set `PrintError` flag, it will warn you. You can catch warnings by trapping a warning signal, as shown [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483622/how-can-i-catch-the-output-from-a-carp-in-perl) or [on PerlMaven](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-capture-and-save-warnings-in-perl).
- If you don't set either one, you get "false" return value from `parse()` but no idea of what the error was.

This is covered in `parse()`'s [POD if you check it](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/SQL-Statement-1.402/lib/SQL/Parser.pm#The_parse_structure):

> In addition to checking the return value of parse() with a
>   variable like $success, you may use the PrintError and
>   RaiseError attributes as you would in a DBI script:
>
> - If PrintError is true, then SQL syntax errors will be sent as
>     warnings to STDERR (i.e. to the screen or to a file if STDERR
>     has been redirected).  This is set to true by default which
>     means that unless you specifically turn it off, all errors
>     will be reported.
> - If RaiseError is true, then SQL syntax errors will cause the
>     script to die, (i.e. the script will terminate unless wrapped
>     in an eval).  This is set to false by default which means
>     that unless you specifically turn it on, scripts will
>     continue to operate even if there are SQL syntax errors.

Comment: As a side note, this sounds as a really dodgy way to parse SQL. What if there's a comma or " = " present in a string literal in SQL?

Comment: DVK - The question is not whether my SQL is proper to parse, the question is how do I catch such SQLs and print an error message if any improper SQL is parsed.

Comment: By the way the problem is due to TO_DATE function only. When I parse the following SQL, it passes: `code`uPdate scott.emp set ename='SCT%',emp_date='04/16/2011', empno='15645' WHERE dept=20 and ename IN(select ename f rom emp where empno='1111');`code`